# XML tag closing in hierarchical manner

Tags: xml, perl

Hi,I've problem in multilevel tag closing,i want to close the tags form the inner level then come to close its outer level e.g

```
<P_Normal><list-bull></P_Normal>
<P_list-bull(1)>Use Microsoft Windows accessibility</P_list-bull(1)>
<P_list-simple(2)>Magnify the display </P_list-simple(2)>
<P_list-simple(2)>Change the size of text and icons</P_list-simple(2)>
<P_list-bull(1)>Adjust background colours </P_list-bull(1)>
<P_Normal></list-bull></P_Normal>
```

my output should be like the below code

```
<list list-type="bullet">
<list-item><p>Use Microsoft Windows accessibility options to:
<list list-type="simple">
<list-item><p> Magnify the display</p></list-item>
<list-item><p> Change the size of text and icons</p></list-item>
</list></p></list-item>
<list-item><p> Adjust background colours</p></list-item>
</list>
```

I try the below code but it display the single list item only

```
while($str =~ /<list-(bull|num|alpha)(?:(?:(?!<\/list-\1>).)*)<\/list-\1>/sgi){
    $str =~ s#<list-(bull|num|alpha)(?:(?:(?!<\/list-\1>).)*)<\/list-\1>#&ListFind($&)#sgei;
}
sub ListFind{
my $line = @_;
my $currentlevel = 0;
while($line =~ s#^[\s\S]*?<(P_list-(\w+)\((\d+)\))>(.*?)</\1>\s*##g)
{
my ($tag, $kind, $level, $text) = ($1, $2, $3, $4);
if ($currentlevel < $level) {
while($currentlevel < $level) {
        $line= "\n<list list-type=$kind>\n<list-item><p>";

        $currentlevel++;
    }
 } elsif ($currentlevel > $level) {
    # close lists down to the given level
    while($currentlevel > $level) {
        $currentlevel--;
        $line ="</p></list-item>\n</list>\n";
    }
    $line = "</p></list-item>\n<list-item><p>";

  } else {
    # close former item
   $line = "</p></list-item>\n<list-item><p>";

  }
  $line .= $text;
 }
 while($currentlevel > 0) {
 $currentlevel--;
 $line .= "</p></list-item>\n</list>\n";

 }
 return "$line";
 }
```

Comment: Crossposted at [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=946979)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Perl SAX](http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/perl-sax/). That should put you on the right path.

Comment: Hi,james i want to close those tag without parsing the XML file pls rectify my mistake in my above code pls

Comment: Your code is getting to the point where it's easier to just parse the XML. There are many XML modules, and I bet most of them are easier to use than SAX.

Comment: The problem is the input is not XML.